# how to call this method when pressing the button

Tags: objective-c, ipad, mkmapview

How to call this below method when pressing the dynamic button?

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
    calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a delegate method of the map view so your code does not call it directly.  The map view calls that method when an annotation view's rightCalloutAccessoryView or leftCalloutAccessoryView is tapped.

When creating the map view, set its delegate property and in the viewForAnnotation method, create a button and set it as the rightCalloutAccessoryView or leftCalloutAccessoryView.

For example:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *annotationIdentifier = @"annot";
    MKPinAnnotationView *pav = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];
    if (!pav)
    {
        pav = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier] autorelease];
        pav.canShowCallout = YES;
        UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        pav.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
    }
    else {
        pav.annotation = annotation;
    }

    return pav;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    //handle tap on annotation...
}
```